# Inmutable NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this example

```
import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Person : NSObject
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *name; 
@end
@implementation Person
@end
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        Person *p = [Person new];
        NSString *name = @"Alice";

        p.name = name;
        NSLog(@"%@",p.name); // prints Alice

        NSString *nameBob = @"Bob";

        name = nameBob;
        NSLog(@"%@",p.name); // prints Alice }
    }
    }
```

I know NSString is immutable, I cannot modify their content ("Alice"), but I can change where NSString is pointing (name = nameBob). 
Why the last NSLog does not print "Bob"?

Comment: Because you change `name` but log `p.name`.

Comment: They are 2 different pointers. Redirecting the `name` pointer does NOT redirect the `name` pointer on your person.

Comment: In what language would this work the way you are expecting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Name is a pointer to a string.

p.name is another pointer to a string.

First you set name to point to a string @"Alice"

Then you set p.name to point to the same string, "Alice". You are not setting p.name to point to name, you are setting it to point to the same address that name points to. (the string "Alice")

Then later you set name to point to a different string, "Bob".

The p.name variable is still pointing to the fist string, "Alice".

Comment: Note that the answer to the above is totally different if you're using the Swift `String` type. Swift Strings are value types, so every time you assign a value to a Swift String it gets copied, unlike with `NSString` objects, which are reference types.